# How to write how much a subject is in compliance with a guideline?

Tags: meaning, cultural-correctness

I need to name a calculator service that should score how much a subject is in compliance with a guideline.

Some of my alternatives are

- Guideline adherence score < Most used in my native language (pt-BR)
- Guideline compliance score
- Guideline according score
- Guideline attending score

What is the most common or more understandable alternative in the English language?

Comment: Sorry, these types of naming questions are out of scope at EL&U.

Comment: *Compliance score* sounds like that you’re looking for.

Comment: Sorry to say both that I agree with Lawrence and the phrasing "How to write how much a subject is in compliance with a guideline" is part of the problem.

Could you rephrase the Question at leat two different ways to account for that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Adherence  and Compliance describe the extent to which the company adheres or complies with some standard. According and Attending make no comment on the company or their ability.
When you say "Name" I take it as "Describe". Your description appears to be used in a stand alone form. 
I think what you wish to do is quantify how well the company matches the standard set forth.
For this I think Guideline matching or Guideline agreement score would work fine.